# Propel and build.properties file

Tags: propel

Whenever I run propel-gen on a clean database (no tables defined), it generates errors because  it first tries to DROP a table (Which doesnt currently exist) before creating it.

Is there any properties I can change to fix this?

So far I've found this:
http://www.propelorm.org/ticket/732

But it would be nice to do something like "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS name"

Comment: What database are you using? What version of Propel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem some months ago but couldn't find more than the trac ticket (you will find, as well, that I have commented it :-)).

Maybe try to apply Elan Ruusamäe's patch if you find this bug very annoying...

If I have enough time/motivation, I may write a patch too (to make Propel issue a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` for DBMS supporting it) and hopefully the fix will be scheduled for one of the next versions.